# Append data to the nested redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-chartjs

I am working on creating a `Line chart` in `react-chartjs`, for that I am fetching data from an API at regular interval and and on success I am dispatching an action that updates the `reducer-state`. I have an initial data in my redux store as

```
var lagData = [{
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'top'
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'ETL lag in minutes'
         },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom'
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    },
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Current lag',
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                spanGaps: false,
                data: []
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

In this store I am trying to append data to the `label` and `data` tags. But I can't figure out how, I am trying it as follows but it doesn't work

```
const lagInfo = (state = lagData, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'GET_CURRENT_LAG_RECEIVED': 
            console.log(action.data);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    data: Object.assign({}, state.data.datasets.data, {
                        x: "afsa",
                        y: "fa"
                    })
                });
            break;
        case 'GET_CURRENT_LAG_ERROR':
            console.log(action.err);
            return action.err;
            break;
        default:
            return state;

    }
}

export default lagInfo;
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`immutability-helper`](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) to update state in an immutable way. The code should look like:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper'; //import helper
// ....
case 'GET_CURRENT_LAG_RECEIVED': 
  return update(state, {
    0: {
      data: {
         datasets: {
           0: {
              data: {$push: [{ x: "afsa", y: "fa"}]}
            }
         }
      }
    }
 })
//...
```

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5w3asrj8/6/) with an example (there is used deprecated [`react-addons-update`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), but they have same behaviour).

**NOTE:** Your `lagData` is array. Shouldn't it be an object, since it is a state? In example above I've assumed that it should be and object, but if for some reasons you still have to deal with an array - here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5w3asrj8/7/).

**PS**: Even more better, is to keep your state as an immutable object, for example with the help of [this tool](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/). I would suggest to loo towards it!

Comment: I will look into that too.

Comment: doesn't help, gives me an error that datasets is undefined

Comment: Alexander state is also an array so you need to access it by index too. Can you edit your answer to depict that issue  too. I already solved this after your first post, but I will accept you answer. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks! And glad to help you! :)

Comment: I have kept it as an array purpose fully because in my code I am checking for the length of data and my data varies across API's that I am hitting